# comparing string object with string literal in C++: why no compile errors?

Tags: c++, string, compiler-errors

I wrote some code like this:

```
#include<string>  
using namespace std;  
int main() {  
    string str;
    ...
    if(str=="test")    //valid????
        //do something
    ...
    return 0;
}
```

After re-reading the code later I was curious that how did the compiler give no errors?
Note: I already checked the reference and it looks like there should be some sort of type mismatch error (comparing string object with array of char)

edit: sorry for the = to == typo error. it is already fixed

edit 2: issues:

- there aren't any of operator==(string,char*) or
  operator==(string,char[]) or similar operators defined in the
  reference(cppreference.com)
- no conversion operator from
  char* or char[] to string

Comment: I don't see why no error either.  I _get_ an error when I try and compile the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have mentioned, the single `=` sign performs assignment, not comparison.

But the comparison operator is defined, like assignment, by [operator overloading](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators), one of the most essential features of C++.

The expression `str = "test"` is transformed into a function call `str.operator= ("test")`, and the expression `str == "test"` would be transformed into either `str.operator== ("test")`, or `operator==(str,"test")`, whichever one works.

Even if the overload function weren't defined for operands of `std::string` and `char *`, the compiler would still try to find function(s) to convert the arguments to types that did match such a function.

**EDIT:** Hah, `std::string` cannot be converted to `bool` so the `if` condition would still be an error. I assume this is an artifact of making a nice snippet for the question.

Comment: the == operator is defined for operator==(string&,string&) but there's no conversion from char* to string or char[] to string or some sort of that

Comment: @TheemathasChirananthavat The `==` operator is defined for `(std::string const&, char const *)`, and the constructor `std::string::string( char const * )` serves as a conversion function.

Comment: thanks! I reviewed the conversion rules and found that the constructor will  be implicitly called for conversion (that's new knowledge to me) BTW 'operator==(str::string const&, char const*)' isn't defined but the implicit conversion just solves the issue

Answer (score 2):

```
if(str="test")  //it's an assignment not a comparison.
```

change it to `if(str=="test")`

```
 why no compile errors?
```

Because it's c++ not c. `std::string` has defined this `==` operator .

```
if(str="test")  //it's an error: because you can't convert string to boolean type. 
                  which is expected as condition.

error like :could not convert 's.std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator=
<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(((const char*)"p"))' from 
'std::basic_string<char>' to 'bool'
```

Comment: But his code is `if ( str = "test" )`, which should give an error: there is no implicit conversion of `std::string` to anything which can be converted to `bool`.

Answer (score 0):

If you do this

```
if(str="test"){}
```

you assign "test" to `str`. As this is a valid operation, the assignment will return `&str` a reference to your object, so your if-condition will always be fulfilled. Of course, if `str == 0` then it will give an error.
So better do:

```
if(str == "test"){}
```

Thanks to James Kanze!

Comment: False.  The assignment returns `std::string&`, which doesn't have an implicit conversion to `bool` (unless his compiler is completely broken).  This is one of the reasons, in fact, why `std::string` doesn't have an implicit conversion to `char const*` either.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, it isn't compilation error due the operator overloading (ignoring the fact that you're not comparing but assigning). If you use any object without this operator then, yes, it will be a compilation error:

```
// Foo does not have comparision operator
struct Foo {};

// Bar have comparision operator
struct Bar
{
    // Next line is the operator overload.
    bool operator ==(const char *pstr) const { return true; };
};

// string have comparision operator
std::string Test("test");

if (Foo == "test")  // compilation error
if (Bar == "test")  // uses the Bar::operator ==
if (Test == "test") // uses the basic_string<char>::operator ==
{ /* do something */ }
```

Comment: What if `Foo` defines `operator char * () { return 0; }`? ;)

Comment: @Potatoswatter Or `operator bool()`, or `operator void*()` (as do the standard streams).

Comment: I can't find any overloads for operator==(const string&,const char*) or operator==(const string&,const char*) or anything similar in the reference